# Changing the GetOutput() Method so it returns details C#

Tags: c#

This was a sort of last resort kind of thing. I was given a question on one of my labs that I'm having issues with and I can't sort it out or even Understand it as I'm really bad at C#!
Anyway the initial question is:
In the class `DogChorus`, change the `GetOutput()` Method so it returns details of all dogs created including the number of legs that all dogs have. There was a hint which was 'you need to call the static `NoOfLegs` property you created through the class name.
Any help/ tips anyone can give me would be greatly appreciated!
Code below for both classes:

```
namespace HelloDogs
{
    class Dog
    {
        private string barkSound;
        private string breed;
        private int dogHeight;
        private static int noOfLegs;

        public static int NoOfLegs
        {
            get { return Dog.noOfLegs; }
            set { Dog.noOfLegs = value; }
        }

        public int DogHeight
        {
        get { return dogHeight; }
        set { dogHeight = value; }
        }
        private string dogColour;

        public string DogColour
        {
        get { return dogColour; }
        set { dogColour = value; }
        }

        public string Breed
        {
            get { return breed; }
            set { breed = value; }
        }
        private string dogSpeech;

        public Dog()
        {
            barkSound = "Woof!";
            breed = "cocker spaniel";
            dogHeight = 25;
            dogColour = " White";
        }

     private bool isBig (int y)
        {
            int dogHeight = y;
            if(dogHeight <50)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

     public string GetSpeech(int theDog)
     {
         if (isBig(theDog))
         {

             dogSpeech = "Hello. I am a " + breed + ". I am big.  " + "I am " + dogHeight + " cm high! " +
             "My coat is " + dogColour + barkSound;
             return dogSpeech;

         }
         else
         {

             dogSpeech = "Hello. I am a " + breed + ". I am small. " + "I am " + dogHeight + " cm high! " +
             "My coat is " + dogColour + barkSound;
             return dogSpeech;
         }
     }

        public void SetSound(String barkSound)
        {
            this.barkSound = barkSound;
        } 
            public Dog(int dogHeight, string dogColour, string breed)
            {
                this.dogHeight = dogHeight;
                this.dogColour = dogColour;
                this.breed = breed;
            }
        }
    }

namespace HelloDogs
{
    class DogChorus
    {
        Dog lady;
        Dog tramp;
        Dog griff;
        Dog lass;

        public DogChorus()
        {
            lady = new Dog();
            tramp = new Dog();
            griff = new Dog();
            lass = new Dog();
            tramp.SetSound("Ruff!");
            lass.SetSound("Howl!");
        }

        public string GetOutput()
        {
            return Dog.GetSpeech() + " \n " + Dog.NoOfLegs() + " \n " + Dog.Getbreed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While *homework help* is not (in general) frowned upon on StackOverflow, homework help for such a *specific* (not to mention *simple*) problem tends to be a bit ill-received. You should give it an *honest* effort first, and then if *you still have a specific problem* you can come back and ask for help on the *specific problem.* (*Specific problem* being an **error message** et al.)

Comment: The purpose of the excercise is that you try to figure it out and learn something: This sentence `it returns details of all dogs created including the number of legs` means that the properties of a dog `dogHeight, Breed, DogColour` should be returned. Now you have several options to change what `GetOutput()` returns. Could you describe what you have tried and where you are stuck?

Comment: The question looks like a request for a code-writing service. Please consider re-formatting and include your code snippets highlighting just a problematic part. Kind regards,

Comment: I've been trying to do it for the last couple of hours haha! But I undersand, the error that popped up most, and still is, is for this specific part: 
public string GetOutput()
        {
            return Dog.GetSpeech() + " \n " + Dog.NoOfLegs() + " \n " + Dog.Getbreed();
        }
and the error is No Overload for GetSpeech takes 0 arguments.

Comment: @user3191460 That's because `GetSpeech` requires you to refer to it as an instance-method, and provide an `int` value for `theDog`. Sample usage of it (best I can gather): `lady.GetSpeech(lady.DogHeight)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have this line:

```
return Dog.GetSpeech() + " \n " + Dog.NoOfLegs() + " \n " + Dog.Getbreed();
```

Although `NoOfLegs` is a static property, `GetSpeech` and `Breed` are not.  (`Getbreed` is not even declared anywhere).  These two should be accessed through an instance, such as `lady.Breed` to get a specific dog's data.

So, you will want to access the `GetSpeech` and `Breed` calls for each of your *instances*.  That is to say: `lady`, `tramp`, `griff`, and `lass`.

Also, as `NoOfLegs` and `Breed` are *properties*, not *methods*, you do not put the parenthesis at the end. Just `Dog.NoOfLegs` or `lady.Breed`.

Also, the `GetSpeech()` method needs some re-writing.  It should probably not take any parameters.

Good luck.